# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING - json without key

Tags: java, android, json

I'm generally a beginner in Android and json, and I'm stuck on one part and need some help. I'm trying to use Rotten Tomatoes json. I managed read almost everything, except the part where there isn't key in json. Here is the json:

```js
{
  "movies": [{
    "id": "771359313",
    "title": "Dumb and Dumber To",
    "year": 2014,
    "mpaa_rating": "PG-13",
    "runtime": 109,
    "critics_consensus": "",
    "release_dates": {
      "theater": "2014-11-14"
    },
    "ratings": {
      "critics_rating": "Rotten",
      "critics_score": 25,
      "audience_rating": "Spilled",
      "audience_score": 54
    },
    "synopsis": "Jim Carrey and Jeff Daniels reprise their signature roles as Lloyd and Harry in the sequel to the smash hit that took the physical comedy and kicked it in the nuts: Dumb and Dumber To. The original film's directors, Peter and Bobby Farrelly, take Lloyd and Harry on a road trip to find a child Harry never knew he had and the responsibility neither should ever, ever be given. The Farrelly brothers produce Dumb and Dumber To alongside Riza Aziz and Joey McFarland of Red Granite Pictures. They are joined by fellow producers Charles B. Wessler and Bradley Thomas. Universal Pictures will distribute the film in the United States, Canada and select international territories.(C) Universal",
    "posters": {
      "thumbnail": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/88/11178864_tmb.jpg",
      "profile": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/88/11178864_tmb.jpg",
      "detailed": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/88/11178864_tmb.jpg",
      "original": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/88/11178864_tmb.jpg"
    },
    "abridged_cast": [{
      "name": "Jim Carrey",
      "id": "162659418",
      "characters": ["Lloyd Christmas"]
    }, {
      "name": "Jeff Daniels",
      "id": "162654392",
      "characters": ["Harry Dunne"]
    }, {
      "name": "Kathleen Turner",
      "id": "162658757",
      "characters": ["Fraida Felcher"]
    }, {
      "name": "Rob Riggle",
      "id": "770750133",
      "characters": ["Travis/Captain Lippincott"]
    }, {
      "name": "Jennifer Lawrence",
      "id": "770800260",
      "characters": ["Young Fraida Felcher"]
    }],
    "alternate_ids": {
      "imdb": "2096672"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771359313.json",
      "alternate": "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/dumb_and_dumber_to/",
      "cast": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771359313/cast.json",
      "reviews": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771359313/reviews.json",
      "similar": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771359313/similar.json"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "771355766",
    "title": "Big Hero 6",
    "year": 2014,
    "mpaa_rating": "PG",
    "runtime": 93,
    "critics_consensus": "",
    "release_dates": {
      "theater": "2014-11-07"
    },
    "ratings": {
      "critics_rating": "Certified Fresh",
      "critics_score": 89,
      "audience_rating": "Upright",
      "audience_score": 94
    },
    "synopsis": "With all the heart and humor audiences expect from Walt Disney Animation Studios, \"Big Hero 6\" is an action-packed comedy-adventure about robotics prodigy Hiro Hamada, who learns to harness his genius-thanks to his brilliant brother Tadashi and their like-minded friends: adrenaline junkie Go Go Tamago, neatnik Wasabi, chemistry whiz Honey Lemon and fanboy Fred. When a devastating turn of events catapults them into the midst of a dangerous plot unfolding in the streets of San Fransokyo, Hiro turns to his closest companion-a robot named Baymax-and transforms the group into a band of high-tech heroes determined to solve the mystery. (C) Disney",
    "posters": {
      "thumbnail": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/85/11178581_tmb.jpg",
      "profile": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/85/11178581_tmb.jpg",
      "detailed": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/85/11178581_tmb.jpg",
      "original": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/85/11178581_tmb.jpg"
    },
    "abridged_cast": [{
      "name": "Ryan Potter",
      "id": "771360315",
      "characters": ["Hiro Hamada"]
    }, {
      "name": "Scott Adsit",
      "id": "406975480",
      "characters": ["Baymax"]
    }, {
      "name": "T.J. Miller",
      "id": "770690115",
      "characters": ["Fred"]
    }, {
      "name": "Jamie Chung",
      "id": "770694653",
      "characters": ["Go Go Tomago"]
    }, {
      "name": "Damon Wayans Jr.",
      "id": "770822247",
      "characters": ["Wasabi"]
    }],
    "alternate_ids": {
      "imdb": "2245084"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771355766.json",
      "alternate": "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/big_hero_6/",
      "cast": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771355766/cast.json",
      "reviews": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771355766/reviews.json",
      "similar": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771355766/similar.json"
    }
  }],
  "links": {
    "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit=2&country=us",
    "alternate": "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/movie/box-office/"
  },
  "link_template": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit={num-results}&country={country-code}"
}
```

Now, I managed to get name, id, but not the characters. Here are some parts of the code how I got it to work:

```js
public class Movie {
  String actor_name;
  public Movie(String response, int index) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MoviesContainer movie = gson.fromJson(response.trim(), MoviesContainer.class);
    List < MovieData > movies = movie.movie
    AbridgedCastData[] aCast = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(movies.get(index).abridged_cast), AbridgedCastData[].class);
    actor_name = aCast[0].name;
  }
}

class MovieData {
  Object abridged_cast;
}

class MoviesContainer {
  public List < MovieData > movies;
}

class AbridgedCastData {
  String name;
  String id;
  Object characters;
}
```

I'm using directly index for testing purposes, so actor_name works perfectly.

I tried like this :

```
CharactersData[] character = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(aCast[0].characters), CharactersData[].class);
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

I searched everywhere but I can't find how to access characters. How to get for example character Lloyd Christmas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON file is not valid. It should begin with `{` and end with `}`. You can check with an online validator such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). That's why you get this error.

Secondly if you look at the structure of the file, you see that there is an an array called abridged_cast which contains some objects (which you defined fine in your `AbridgedCastData` class).

So the final structure could be:

```
class A {
   //contains a list of objects B or an array of objects B
}

class B {
  //name
  //id
  //characters (list of Strings or String array)
}
```

We are almost done!

When you don't specify a `SerializedName` annotation, the parser requires that the field name of the attribute you want to serialize must be the same as in the JSON file (otherwise you will end up with a non-initialized value). Since that's not the case you need to add a `@SerializedName("abridged_cast")` annotation.

Finally you end up with:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myJson.json"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MoviesContainer movie = gson.fromJson(br, MoviesContainer.class);
        List<AbridgedCastData> movies = movie.movies;
        System.out.println(movies);
    }
}

class MoviesContainer {
    @SerializedName("abridged_cast")
    public List<AbridgedCastData> movies;
}

class AbridgedCastData {
    String name;
    String id;
    List<String> characters;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AbridgedCastData [name=" + name + ", id=" + id
                + ", characters=" + characters + "]";
    }    
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[AbridgedCastData [name=Jim Carrey, id=162659418, characters=[Lloyd Christmas]], AbridgedCastData [name=Jeff Daniels, id=162654392, characters=[Harry Dunne]], AbridgedCastData [name=Kathleen Turner, id=162658757, characters=[Fraida Felcher]], AbridgedCastData [name=Rob Riggle, id=770750133, characters=[Travis/Captain Lippincott]], AbridgedCastData [name=Jennifer Lawrence, id=770800260, characters=[Young Fraida Felcher]]]
```

Comment: I posted the whole json now, can you please adapt your code so it matches mine code and json, because it's confusing for me now? Thanks.

Comment: @user2692863 I don't get it, why don't you change `Object characters;` to `List<String> characters` since you know that it's a List/Array of Strings ? Then you could just do  `String character = aCast[0].characters[0];` which prints Lloyd Christmas for me. I used the same code as you (except I used a `BufferedReader` like in my example, so `new Movie(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myJson.json")), 0);` and `MoviesContainer movie = gson.fromJson(response, MoviesContainer.class);`). I don't know how you get `response` but this should work if you follow my advices.

Comment: I just did that change but I'm getting error message: Array type expected; found: 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'. My response is from json from tomato, that works fine, I can get everything from json except this.

Comment: @user2692863 I don't know how you get response. What happens when you try to load the file with the BufferedReader? This the working code with the new json file, try it and tell me if it works : http://pastebin.com/TNH5s9Eu

Comment: I know what the problem was now. You told me to use List<String> characters. This is a list, and I should use aCast[0].characters.get[0]. But in your code on pastebin, you declared array like this String[] characters; and now aCast[0].characters[0]; works and I get Lloyd Christmas! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user2692863 Yes if its a list use `aCast[0].characters.get(0);` Glad it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

you could change your response and then parse it.

```
response = "{" + response + "}" ;
// now parse json
```